# How to add keyboard shortcut for opening Styles drop down in CKEditor v4?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

how can i add keyboard shortcut to open styles drop down / richcombo in ckeditor version 4?

part of config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.keystrokes = [
        // ALT + minus(numpad)
        [CKEDITOR.ALT + 109, 'formattingstyles'],
    ];
}
```

above code does not work because [ckeditor styles plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/stylescombo) does not `addCommand`